# SQL: convert decimal field to text field and remove decimals

Tags: sql

I'm looking to convert a field with decimal values (format: decimal, length: 18) to a text field and lop off the '.00' portion of the decimal field. All of the values in the field have a decimal of '.00'. I was trying to use a combination of convert and truncate but it didn't work:

```
SELECT convert(varchar(15),truncate(a.CADS_ID_Number__c,0)) as 'CADS_ID_Number__c',
```

sample value
721722.00

```
SELECT convert(varchar(15),truncate(a.CADS_ID_Number__c,0)) as 'CADS_ID_Number__c',
```

wouldn't validate my syntax.

was trying to convert '721722.00' from a decimal field with length 18 to a text field:
'721722'

Comment: Tag your question with the specific database engine you're using; `sql` is too general. The logic for converting and rounding values likely needs DB-specific syntax. `TRUNCATE` does not exist in the T-SQL dialect of SQL Server, for example. Also, what is the *exact* data type of the column `a.CADS_ID_Number__c`, so not just the values it contains or how these happen to be presented by the front-end?

Comment: Both truncate and convert are product specific functions. Which dbms? (Also, tables have _columns_, not fields.)

Comment: Why do you want to store numerical values as text? That's the origin of many problems.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please use below query,

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), CAST(a.CADS_ID_Number__c as INT)) as 'CADS_ID_Number__c'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FORMAT() function, like this:

```
SELECT  FORMAT(a.CADS_ID_Number__c, '0.##')
```

This will truncate redundant decimal zeros, but other will remain up to 2 decimal numbers.

Examples:

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| 12.000 | 12 |
| 12.300 | 12.3 |
| 12.340 | 12.34 |
| 12.342 | 12.34 |